# Android SDK Manager showing no System Images

Tags: android, windows, sdk

I have been fighting this all day with no success.  I have removed & re-installed the SDK multiple times, I've tried http:// and https://, I've cleared cache..  I'm at a loss.

I'm on W10 x64.  My Android SDK Manager shows no System Images available for download at all.  It shows everything else - all the platforms, documentation, etc. - but no images of ANY kind.

I have tried all the possible combinations of "New/Updates", "Installed", and "Obsolete" to no avail.  I have run the SDK Manager as Administrator, and I am not getting any errors in the log (ie, some users reported "Connection refused" errors).  By all accounts, everything works - but I have no images available.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Images show up under each SDK.  Which SDKs are showing as installed?

Comment: I have installed 19 and 21.  Also interesting to note,  I am a Xamarin subscriber.  Their installer is unable to download the packages.  Perhaps this is a problem at Google?

Comment: My Mac is also unable to download any images.  This feels like a server-side issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, I do think it was definitely some server-side package thing - the images never showed up as options to select for installation, even after Android Studio was reinstalled twice and over two different machines.

For me, it was fixed by upgrading to Android Studio 2.1 when it came out, though I had to wait for that...